# Getting the Angular model value directly from textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and working on a angular directive which used to trigger a modal show event based on the value from the controller with a isolated function which binds model and view with the correct values. But when i get the textbox value directly using jquery it only returns the old value of the model. I have also used $timeout to wait until digest cycle completes. Am i missing something ?

Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<.. ng-repeat='tab in tabs'>
   <a href="#{{tab.id}}" trigger="Ctrl.set(tab)">Show {{tab.name}}</a>    
</..>
```

**Directive**

```
(...).directive('trigger', [..., function($timeout) {
    return {
       restrict:'A',
       scope: {
            trigger:'&'
       },
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {                   
              $(elem).click(function() {   
                 scope.trigger(); // works fine. model binds and shown in the view

                 $timeout(function(){
                    $("#modal").show(); // also working..

                    $("#modal").find('input').each(function(i,e) {                         
                        console.log($(e).val()); // prints the old model values.
                     });
                 },100);
            }

       }
    }
}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

I have added a fiddle for this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashanth702/2hrm0ohr/)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? Hard to figure out the error using only what you have here

Comment: heres the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashanth702/2hrm0ohr/)

Comment: Do not mix angular and jquery. Angular way is to get value from model not from html input element.